# Как установить драйвера для xenserver 7.x?

Tags: linux, сервер, сеть, xen, citrix

Имеется чистый сервер HP Proliant DL360p gen8. Стоит задача установить xenServer. При попытке установить после выбора языка появляется ошибка
"**No network Interfaces**: *This host does not appear to have any network interfaces*"
Пытаюсь установить драйвера...Скачиваю от сюда [ссылка на драйвер с сайта HP support](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_25aee517f1b841a69073ee9c40&swEnvOid=4109). ставлю образ с установленными ISO в виртуальный CD/DVD ROM (через iLO). Нажимаю F9 для автоматического поиска драйверов xen установщика.
Получаю ошибку "**No drivers Found:** *No XenServer compatible drivers where found at the location specified...*"
Следующим шагом пробую установит драйвера с того же CD/DVD с помощью командной строки нажав "ctrl+f2" монтирую ISO с помощью команды **`mount -ro loop /dev/sr0 /media/mnt`** в директории /media/mnt появляется файлы в форматe .rpm и .sh. Пытаюсь установить с помощью файла ./install.sh но в ответ получаю
**`./install.sh : line 170: /etc/xensource-inventory: No such file or directory`**.

Подскажите как решить проблему ?((

Comment: Ну а как мы узнаем, что это за `line 170` в котором прописан путь `/etc/xensource-inventory`? Надо содержимое скрипта смотреть.